# Non modal popup

Tags: firefox-addon

I am opening a popup window:

```js
browser.windows.create({
    allowScriptsToClose: true, // FF Only
    url     : "pop_main.html",
    type    : "popup", // normal, popup, panel, detached_panel
    // focused : true, FF NOT SUPPORTED
    width   : 750,
    height  : 520
}, function (pop) {
    popup_id = pop.id;
});
```

Problem is that the window is Modal, as in "always on top", over all FireFox windows.

I would like it to behave like a normal window in that regard. Reason for using "popup" is that the window should not have address-bar, window-menus etc.

Is this possible?